# obter os valores do campos combo antes de gravar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma tabela html com N valores e gostaria de obter os valores dos campos (combo), propriedade name='legenda[]' antes de gravar, apenas para exibir ao usuário os campos que ele preencheu .

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Use `document.getElementsByName("nameOfHTMLElement");`.

Comment: nao funcionou !

Comment: Podes explicar melhor como queres gravar, ou o que queres dizer com "gravar"? Assim posso também dar uma resposta que te ajude com o que precises.

Answer (score 1):

Quando carrega no botão para exibir as escolhas vai ter de percorrer os elementos para ver qual é o valor (escolha) em cada um:

```js
$('#check').on('click', function() {
  var escolhas = '<b>As suas escolhas são:</b><br>';
  $('select').each(function() {
     escolhas += $(this).prop('id')+ ': ' +$(this).val()+ '<br>';
  });
  $('#present').html(escolhas);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Maria">Maria</option>
  <option value="Miguel">Miguel</option>
  <option value="Sara">Sara</option>
  <option value="Claudia">Claudia</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Maria">Maria</option>
  <option value="Miguel">Miguel</option>
  <option value="Sara">Sara</option>
  <option value="Claudia">Claudia</option>
</select>
<select id="select3">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Maria">Maria</option>
  <option value="Miguel">Miguel</option>
  <option value="Sara">Sara</option>
  <option value="Claudia">Claudia</option>
</select>
<br>
<button id="check">
Verificar Escolhas
</button>
<div id="present">
 
</div>
```

Exemplo [AQUI](https://jsfiddle.net/28jrgstk/2/)

Answer (score 0):

tente usar o seguinte código

```
  var valores = $('select[name^=legenda]').map(function(idx, elem) {
    return $(elem).val();
  }).get();
```

ele irá retornar um Array com todos os valores de todos os campos dentro da variável valores

Comment: obrigado Raphael, mais como eu utilizo esse codigo acima ? ja criei uma funcao chamando e nada, tb tentei o alert e nada ... obrigado

Comment: se você puder disponibilizar a parte do seu código javascript em que precisa utilizar isso eu posso te dar um exemplo de uso melhor...